# Spoofing real image url

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, photo, spoofing

For a large high traffic newswebsite we want to start spoofing the direct links to all the photos.

There for we want to create dynamic urls, like Twitter does on there images:
https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Bv_wkiyCUAA0E6f.jpg:large

The same counts for the sizes on the end of the url. How is this done without impacting the webservers extremly?
Our platform works on php/mysql.

Comment: This is a solution of Akamai CDN. The images are getting cached, a non-cache-dynamic solution would cost way too much CPU. You should pregenerate all the images and if you can, not be using PHP as it will eat more memory and CPU.

Comment: Try `Varnish Cache` with nginx or Apache.

Comment: All images (in all sizes) are pre-renderd and on the storage. So we dont have to do the resizing here.

Answer (score 0):

Back a while ago we had the same problem to solve.
We did the following:
We've opened a symlink to the original image once the page were loaded (while loading), and printed the link URL as